Expectation score of exam when randomly answering is 0
A multiple-choice exam is given. A problem has four possible answers, of which exactly one is correct.
A student is allowed to mark any subset of the possible answers. The student receives 3 points if the
correct answer is marked, and is penalized by 1 point for each wrong answer.
Suppose the student
marks his answers randomly, where each possible answer is marked with some probability.
(Distinct
answers are not necessarily marked with the same probability.) Show that the expected score of the
student is 0.
My approach: I was trying to define $X$ - to count the score of the student, and then tried to define it as $X=Y_1 + Y_2$, as $Y_1$ is 3 if the correct answer was marked and $Y_2$ takes the values -1,-2,-3. But it's just a long calculations.
Is there any other possible way to solve this quicker?

I am not sure but maybe you can use the formula of expectation probability here

Use linearity.  Show your expectation on a single question is $0$, then sum.

What do you mean by "(Distinct answers are not necessarily marked with the same probability.)"

@lulu it's long approach not sure how.

@trueblueanil that means that we have 4 questions, A,B,C,D and marking each one of them is given with probability $P_A,P_B,P_C,P_D$ accordingly, and the correct answer is either one of them with probability 1/4

You need to clarify the probability.  I assumed that you were just guessing at random and had a $\frac 14$ chance of being right in each case.  Obviously, if the correct answer is more likely to be $A$ or whatever, then you'll guess $A$ exclusively and increase your expected score.

Using my reading, the computation is not long at all.  The expectation for a single question is $\frac 14\times 3-\frac 34\times 1 =0$ and summing over the questions yields $0$ for the total expected value.  But, as I say, if you have more information on the correct answers you can increase your expected score.

Does this somebody know that exactly one answer is correct? Does he mark the answers independently?

I think that as worded, the stated result of this exercise is not correct. The expectation is $0$ if the student has the same chance to mark each of the four answers on each question (different probabilities for different questions is OK). But suppose the student marks (a) with probability $1$, (b) with probability $0.8$, (c) with probability $0$, and (d) with probability $0.5$, whereas the test maker has written the test so that (c) is the correct response to every question.

@DavidK I clarified the correct answer could be either A B C OR D with probability 1/4 for each

You should edit that information into the question. Even better would be if it could be explained how the random distribution of correct answers is implemented. Is the answer key (listing the correct answers) constructed at random after the student has turned in the exam? At the time when the student is marking answers, in what sense is the correct answer "random"?

We could rescue this question from philosophical conundrums by stating that we want the student's expected score at a time when their strategy for marking answers is completely determined and the test has not yet been written, with the proviso that the test writer writes four answers, one correct and three incorrect, and then randomly permutes them with $1/4$ chance of putting the correct answer in each of the four labeled positions.

I suppose the simplest resolution to the problem statement is simply to ignore how the test is administered and state the $1/4$ probability as a given fact. That is, we compute the expected score from the point of view of someone who knows that the student will follow a strategy as described in the question and who, having no knowledge of what will be on the test or how it was constructed (aside from the fact that there are always one correct and three incorrect choices) assumes the $1/4$ probability of an answer being correct.

I'm assuming you didn't come up with this problem yourself, so you're not responsible for all the ambiguities about what it actually means.

Thanks @DavidK that helped

Let us find the expectation of marking any given option on any question.
With probability $\frac 14$, the answer is correct, and with probability $\frac 34$ it is incorrect. So the expected value is $3 \times \frac 14 - 1 \times \frac 34 = 0$.
As this holds for every answer, it doesn't matter what strategy the student chooses as we can express their total score as the sum of the score from all possible answers and use linearity of expectation.

I haven't studied the expected of two variables yet.

@DavidK oh, i missed that detail! in that case the answer is even shorter

And this version of the answer works even if we change the wording of the problem so that the student only marks one answer per question. One needs linearity of expectation to fully understand the answer, but the key step in the reasoning really is this simple.
